# Why ATL calls subclassing "superclassing"

Tags: visual-c++, atl, superclass

Getting interested in learning ATL, I started reading [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260759.aspx) and I got confused at reading this [(also related)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260759.aspx#atlwindow_topic8):

> If you want to extend the capabilities of a predefined window class, such as the button or list box controls, you can superclass it.

Why is it called *super*-classing instead of *sub*-classing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super-classing is writing a new class, that would behave as it it was a new control altogether. A CColoredButton inheriting from `CButton` would be superclass, when you **create instance of `CColoredButton`**

When you already have a control (probably on resource), you may subclass it. Here the "control" in picture is being handled differently and hence the term subclass.

Any class may behave as super class or subclass. You would call some of `SubclassXX` function/method to subclass already existing control. You would create instance of a control at runtime by allocating the C++ object (`CColoredButton`) by calling its `Create` method - here the term super-class.